# Access Generics List in ASP.NET MVC 5 View

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am getting started with MVC and I have the following Model

```
public class FormControls
{

    //Properties of the FormControls object
    public string formCName { get; set; }
    public string formCType { get; set; }
    public string formCCss { get; set; }
    public string formCEnabled { get; set; }
    public string formCDefaultVal { get; set; }

}
```

I also created the following control and I am querying a database using linq to select records. Each record will then have to be added to a list.

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var DataContext = new EditProfileFormFieldsDataContext();
        var controls = from c in DataContext.Controls
                       select c;

        List<FormControls> Fields = new List<FormControls>();

        foreach(var fc in controls)
        {


            //Create Object for Generic List
            FormControls epc = new FormControls();
            epc.formCName = fc.Control_Name;
            epc.formCType = fc.Control_Type;
            epc.formCCss = fc.Control_CSS;
            epc.formCEnabled = fc.Control_Enabled;
            epc.formCDefaultVal = fc.Control_DefaultVal;

            //Add Object to FormControls Generic List
            Fields.Add(epc);
        }



        return View("EditProfile");
    }
```

My question is how would I access the list using RAZOR in the view? I am trying to loop through the list I created in the view. I am fairly new to MVC and I think I am over thinking a lot of this :) Thanks!

Comment: In your `Index` method, collect the list with: `var formControls = DataContext.Controls.ToList(); return View(formControls);`. Then create a view by right clicking on `View`. Create the view with a model. Select your model and your db context. Make the view of type `List` and **BOOM**, you're done. Since you're new, it helps to make as much use of the IDE as possible. Oh and when the IDE creates the `List` view for you. Study it and the next time you'll know exactly what to do. Do the same with other view types like `create`, `edit`, `details`, `delete`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the model of your view a List. Put this at the top of your view:

```
@model List<FormControls>
```

Change the return of your `Index()` method:

```
return View("EditProfile", Fields);
```

Then you can access it from the view by using @Model. For example, to iterate through it:

```
@foreach (var field in Model)
{
    <p>@field.formCName</p>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Btw, there is a more direct way to implement the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var DataContext = new EditProfileFormFieldsDataContext();
    return View("EditProfile", DataContext.Controls.ToList());
}
```

or if you rename the view to "index.cshtml", you can do it like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var DataContext = new EditProfileFormFieldsDataContext();
    return View(DataContext.Controls.ToList());
}
```

Suppose you do not have the index.cshtml yet, right click the "View(" and select "Add View", in the pop-up wizard, select "list view" and FormControls, there will be an auto-generated view with @model defined and a well done table demoing how to use it.